# mysql and php rare not communicating

Tags: source-code

```
$db_server = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Kazibwe') or die(mysql_error());
```

have failed to connect and receive no error in my browser, actually the browser shows nothing. please help

Comment: Do you have `libapache2-mod` and `mysql` modules installed and enabled in your apache, but first off - is this also happening when you run other pages with `php` from you browser ?

Comment: Add this on top of your PHP script after the `<?php` tag so as to show errors on the browser:  `ini_set("display_errors",1);` Then edit your question and include the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment, so I must answer you this way:

Do you have installed the following packages on your db server:

```
libapache2-mod-php5

php5-mysql
```

If not, then run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Do :

```
 sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

This will install all missing files with complete LAMP-STACK

Comment: Also tell where are u keeping your site pages?